# EntityListner on @onetoMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am doing some audit logging through @entitylistners of java persistence API. I have a scenario of one to many entity relationship where one student can have multiple subjects.

Student Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@EntityListeners(AuditInterceptor.class)
public class Student
{   
  @id
  @column("student_id")
  private Integer studentId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)    
  private Set<Subjects> subjects= new HashSet<Subjects>(0);    
  // getter and setter

}
```

SUBJECT Entity

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "subject")        
    public class Subject
    {   
      @id
      @column("subject_id")
      private Integer subjectId;

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")  
      private Student student;   
      // getter and setter

    }
```

Audit Interceptor Class

```
public class AuditInterceptor
{
  @PreUpdate
  public void preUpdate(Object entity)
  {
     //anycode
  }
}
```

on UI,one student can select multiple subjects. So whenever student entity gets updated, my call to @preUpdate method comes in. here are possible cases of auditing.

1. When student entity gets change (like student name)--control should go to @preUpdate
2. When student and subject both gets change (add/remove subject list to student AND update student name)--control should go to @preUpdate
3. When only subject get change (only add/remove subject list)

My 3rd case is failing
Question: Whenever student's subject gets changed then my interceptor is not calling. On dao layer I am just using JPA repository SAVE method for updating he entity.
I need whenever my child entity gets changed then my parent entity reference should also needs to change so that my interceptor can understand that Student entity has been changed.